# reading and writing to a file with fstream

Tags: c++, fstream, seekg

```
bool remove_vowels(const std::string& file_name) {

    std::fstream fs{ file_name , std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out };   
    if (!fs) { std::cout << "Error file not open"; return false; }

    char in{};

    while (fs >> in) {

        switch (tolower(in)) { 

        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
        {
            int64_t pos{ fs.tellg() }; 
            fs.seekp(pos - 1);         
            fs << ' ';                 
            fs.seekg(pos);
            
            break;
        }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I try to solve one exercise from: Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ Bjarne Stroustrup

> 3. Write a program that removes all vowels from a file (“disemvowels”). For
>    example, Once upon a time! becomes nc pn tm!. Surprisingly often, the
>    result is still readable; try it on your friends.

The text file contain: "Once upon a time"

When i try this code inside the switch case:

```
int64_t pos { fs.tellg() }; // it get position one character forward
        fs.seekp(pos - 1);  // i set the write position to the the character         
        fs << ' ';          // then i replace the vowel to whitespace and increment one position
```

i get infinite loop that overwrite all the file with these characters "nc "

its only work for me this way:

```
int64_t pos{ fs.tellg() }; 
            fs.seekp(pos - 1);         
            fs << ' ';                 
            fs.seekg(pos);
```

Why it is necessary to set the position after `fs << ' ';`   if its already increases it?

Comment: [Not Reproducible](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zlyTPQXEG1WjHMpK) Working just fine without `fs.seekg(pos)`.

Comment: IMHO, this is not the way to do it. When you take out a vowel the rest of the text has to be 'pulled up' to close the gap. It's much easier to read the entire file into an array, do the processing there, possibly while copying to another array, if that's easier, and then write out the result to file once done.

Comment: Also what else were you expecting other than "nc " there?  It is what one will get after removing vowels from "Once". Surely that's not the complete output that the code should give (actually it's giving complete output in my case, see my comment above), but in no way one can get an infinite loop by not explicitly resetting the position. The ostream extraction operator should increment the position of get/put pointer implicitly.

Comment: @brc-dd, I mean an endless loop that keeps writing ``nc`` not that i have in a file with these characters left. and i think if the writing command do it i dont need to explicit do it

Comment: In C I/O it is necessary to use a file positioning function in between switching from reading to writing or from writing to reading. I guess your example proves that the same requirement exists for C++ I/O.

Comment: @john, thenk you. I tried to find something on the internet that explains it, But maybe this is the situation

Comment: You can open the file  A for read, and another file B  for write. Read A and write to B if it is not a vowel, otherwise skip the writing. After closed file, remove A file, and name B as A.

Comment: ytlu , 500 - Internal Server Error. Thanks for yours suggestions

Comment: @zin There is no statement in the code you posted here which prints to stdout/stderr. Maybe the problem is with your driver function? Because I don't think anything like that should occur in general. Please post the complete code. Hopefully, after that we will be able to explain you more.

Comment: @ytlu Yes that will be my recommendation also, much cleaner and less confusing

Comment: @zin std::ofstream  bFilre("outfile,txt"); std::ifstream aFile("disemvowels.txt");
afile >> a; if (a!='a' || .....) bFile <<a; ......; aFile.close(); bFile.close();
system("rm disemvowel.txt"); system("rename outfile.txt disemvowel.txt");

Comment: @brc-dd. Thanks for the time, I do not write anything to std::cout/cerr, just for the exercise I created a text file that contains the sentence "once upon a time", and I pass to the main function the name of the file and then I go into the file to see with it replaced the letters

Comment: @zin Two of my recommended implementations: [1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GaZ0uOs3UCTfkk3b), [2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Lk5Ay3BiVZ3PRMa0). Give them a look :) [Change implementation of `isVowel` to whatever suits you best.]

Comment: @brc-dd Thenk you.